# Spring boot conflicting gradle dependancies: google oauth client

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am attempting to run a Google Calendar Java sample within my Spring boot application. The Google Calendar sample runs as expected when run in isolation, but one of it's dependancies conflicts with a Spring boot dependancy when they are run together.

In this case I have the following dependancies enabled:
[image: gradle dependancies enabled]

and see the following error when launching Spring boot:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet
```

I can get Spring boot to run making the following dependancy changes and commenting the Google Calendar code that requires

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

[image: gradle dependancies disabled]

Of course, this means the Google Calendar sample won't run anymore...

I think what I need is some way of force targeting specific versions of a dependancy so Spring boot can find the method it's currently missing while allowing the Google Calendar sample to import what it needs, but being new to Spring boot I'd appreciate *any* help or suggestions.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: you can always declare a dependency yourself with a fixed version number, it will take precedence to other transitive dependencies (in Maven this is done with dependencyManagement. not sure how to do that in graddle)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `com.google.api-client` in my gradle (also in spring boot app).
The problem seems to be connected with servlet version provided by google.
I fixed it by adding exclusion in build.gradle compile line:

```
    compile (group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-appengine', version: '1.23.0'){
    exclude group:'javax.servlet'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Albert Mosialek.
In my case I was using maven and I had to insert the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line into file **build.gradle**

```
compile'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
```

I try and run ok.

Hope helpfull with you.